# Use UILabel Class's method differently for Two Label

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, inheritance, uilabel

In my application i have a scrollview that shows **dynamically generated Labels** (some are having **70px height** and some are having **50px height**).

i need to use **- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect** method for both type of label.

for that i created one UILabel controller class and in it there is a method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Drawing code
NSLog(@"draw rect in uilabel class");
UIEdgeInsets insets = {0, 0, -14, 0};
return [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)]; 
}
```

i need to set **one label's insets** = {0, 0, **-14**, 0}; and **another label's** {0, 0, **-22**, 0};
but in a random manner (means for label 1,2,4,6,9 the bottom will be -14 and for 3,5,7,8,10,11 bottom will be -22).

yes I can do this from putting Two UILabel class and getting object from that.

but i need to use this class's methods for two types of labels.

tagging is not useful, i used it.

I would like to do some thing like this

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Drawing code
  if(for label one){
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {0, 0, -14, 0};
    return [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
  }
  else if(for label Two){
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {0, 0, -22, 0};
    return [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
  }
}
```

any idea, code, link, tutorial will be great Help...

------------ **EDIT:** -----------------------------------

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LabelInListViewClass : UILabel

@end
```

and  in .m file

```
#import "LabelInListViewClass.h"

@implementation LabelInListViewClass

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code

    NSLog(@"in Label Class");

}
return self;
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Drawing code
UIEdgeInsets insets = {0, 0, -14, 0};
return [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];

}
```

and in ViewController .m file

```
label1 = [[LabelInListViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16,varForHeight,320, 50)];

label2 = [[LabelInListViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16,varForHeight,320, 70)];
```

Comment: you can create an mutalbearray with numbers say 1 to 11. shuffle the array. extract first one and set the inset for it. repeat till array contains objects.

Comment: ya but it's not static so i cant take this kind of array. because first the label is allocation from this UILabel class and then anything will work. and in my case with the allocation all the class method will call. i need to get difference on allocation of labels.

Answer (score 0):

Make the edge insets value a property of your label subclass, and set the insets when you create the labels. Use the property when drawing instead of creating a local value.

Comment: I stick by my answer. Are you asking me for code, or is there something you don't understand?